# Python dataframe row and column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, header

I am a newB python modeller and currently experiencing some issues with a line of code which may be very basic for a lot of you.

I am using python 2.7 and have successfully used xlwings to copy a named range from external workbook in to the pd.dataframe format. Everything thing works fine except the df.index and df.columns. Currently the code is assigning 1 to n (based on number of rows and columns) numbers as a index and column names.

is there a way, I use the first column values of my imported data as df.index and first row as df.column?

Can some one please assist me with getting something like this:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(myExcelRange, df.index = 'first column values', df.columns = 'first row values')
```

The shape and name of myExcelRange could be different each time.

Any guideline will be much appreciated.

Example:

**> myExcelRange**

```
ITEM    Dan Jane    Fan 
A   77  78  40
B   89  53  72  
C   20  19  79  
D   81  54  93  
E   77  76  99
```

**pandas is returning**

```
    0   1   2   3
0   ITEM    Dan Jane    Fan
1   77  78  40  0
2   89  53  72  0
3   20  19  79  0
4   81  54  93  0
5   77  76  99  0
```

**desired**

```
ITEM    Dan Jane    Fan 
A   76  89  100 
B   59  72  24  
C   69  73  19  
D   70  92  43  
E   65  94  30
```

Comment: what is `type(myExcelRange)` ?

Comment: it's a 'list' type

Comment: Can you add some sample like `myExcelRange = ['a','b','c']` or `myExcelRange = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f']]` and desired output?

Comment: Or you need select first value in column and index by `df = pd.DataFrame(myExcelRange).iat[0,0]` or `df = pd.DataFrame(myExcelRange).iloc[0,0]`? Or rename only first index value and first column value?

Comment: I have been playing with it and used df = df.set_index(0) - this seems to be used the first column values as the index. however, I need to find some set_column kind of function

Comment: Thanks J, I will test your suggestion in a tick.

Comment: @Py_junior, are you aware of the [pd.read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with first column and then select first row by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and assign to `df.columns`, last remove first row from data by `iloc` too:

```
myExcelRange = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['g','h','i']]
df = pd.DataFrame(myExcelRange)
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  a  b  c
1  d  e  f
2  g  h  i

df = df.set_index(0)
df.columns = df.iloc[0,:]
#for nicer df remove index and column names
df.index.name = None
df.columns.name = None

print (df.iloc[1:,:])
   b  c
d  e  f
g  h  i
```

As [Alex Fung](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756809/python-dataframe-row-and-column/41757667?noredirect=1#comment70707188_41756809)  mentioned, maybe is possible use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) with parameter `index_col`:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx', index_col=0)
print (df)
      Dan  Jane  Fan
ITEM                
A      77    78   40
B      89    53   72
C      20    19   79
D      81    54   93
```